# Clang usage of dependency-dot option

Tags: clang, clang++

**TL;DR**: How to use the `-dependency-dot` argument of `clang++`?

I want to compile my `C++`-code while generating the include dependencies as `dot`-formatted graph.
This should be possible as the current [`clang`-doc](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-dependency-dot) states:

> `-dependency-dot <arg>`
>
> Filename to write DOT-formatted header dependencies to

What I tried: `clang++ -dependency-dot m.dot m.C`. 
This resulted in the following warning:

```
clang-5.0.2: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dependency-dot m.dot' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Unsurprisingly, no `dot`-files are produced whatsoever.
This is also the case when adding `-MMD` or `-MD` flags.
I must be using `-dependency-dot` incorrectly.
How can you invoke `clang++` correctly with this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the flags to the clang front end instead of the driver:

```
-Xclang -dependency-dot -Xclang foo.dot
```

Looking at the code, the option is not plumbed from the driver to the frontend.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'll report this as a bug though. Either documentation is misleading or this option should be forwarded.

Answer (score -1):

Lol. I am getting the same problem right now!
However, -dependency-file FILENAME still seems to work.

Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0

Comment: I get similar errors with the `-dependency-file` option. Also with `clang++-6.0`. I'm not familiar with Apple versioning, but given that `llvm-7` is development right now, I don't know what `llvm-9` is.